# Elasticsearch get random document, atleast 5 from each category

Tags: elasticsearch

Searching in internet but no solution. I have 1000 documents with 5 categories. Each category has around 200 documents. I want to pull 30 random documents with at-least 5 from each category. Please suggest me any solution.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31795599/limit-grouped-results-in-elasticsearch (you don't need the filter though). That should give you some idea about nested aggregation. But that approach doesn't randomize and only gives you top_hits, so you may need to do further research.

Comment: Thanks Arun Bhai! I am doing more research on it.

Answer (score 4):

I think you need this page:

> https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html

I tested the basic query with a size limit and I got different results each time. Here is the example code.

```
GET logstash-*/_search
{
  "size": 3, 
    "query": {
        "function_score": {
            "query": { "match_all": {} },
            "boost": "5",
            "random_score": {}, 
            "boost_mode":"multiply"
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know how you can do categorized random, but worst case you can run 5 query for 6 documents.

Comment: i tried this but not successful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47904703/how-to-get-at-least-1-document-of-each-values?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: I tested the example code and it worked. What is your ES version?

Comment: I am getting multiple documents from same category and some categories are skipped.

Comment: Thats what is said in the last lines of the post. I don't see how you can get partially random elements in a query. It's either random, or not random. If it's random, then you have no restriction on the category. So you need 5 different queries that are random and restricted to one category.

Comment: My categories will increase in future, around 40 categories and i pull 30 documents, each from different category. Then it is very horrible to run 30 queries to pull 30 documents.